# PostgreSQL: How to insert a large data set into a table?

Tags: postgresql, dataset

I have a table in PostgreSQL database that I need to add to it 2 million rows. 
When I try to do it with an INSERT INTO query it throws

```
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function cdb_checkquota() line 11 at IF
```

I've tried to reconfigure the **postgresql.conf** file (enlarge the **work_mem** and **statement_timeout**) but it did not work.

Can anyone tell me what I miss here?
BTW, I'm using INSERT INTO query  because I need to replicate the tables data, so I'm coping the tables data without the primary key in order to prevent duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

Best I'm aware, the error is triggered only when `statement_timeout` is set:

```
denis=# select pg_sleep(2);
 pg_sleep 
----------
 
(1 row)
denis=# set statement_timeout to 1;
SET
denis=# select pg_sleep(2);
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

Have you tried to disable it altogether?

```
set statement_timeout to 0
```

That should be the default, btw. And per the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-STATEMENT) (emphasis mine):

> statement_timeout (integer)
> Abort any statement that takes more than the specified number of milliseconds, starting from the time the command arrives at the server from the client. If log_min_error_statement is set to ERROR or lower, the statement that timed out will also be logged. **A value of zero (the default) turns this off.**
>
> **Setting statement_timeout in postgresql.conf is not recommended because it would affect all sessions.**

Comment: Thanks Denis. I've tried it, the settings works but when I'm running the query I'm getting the same result: ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout

Comment: Wouldn't that be an indication that something in your queries, trigger functions or other is messing around with `statement_timeout`?